# what is wrong with Angular js

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In js  I  wrote

```
$scope.check = function () {
    $scope.searchName = "";
    $.post("http://172.22.71.107:8888/check/", {},

    function (arg_result) {
        if (arg_result.Ret == 0) {

            $scope.users = [];
            $scope.users = arg_result.Data;
            console.log($scope.users);
        }
    }, "json");
```

but in html  the data can not update at time when receive the rusult ,what is wrong?

Comment: [`Same Origin Policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)?

Answer (score 2):

You are updating the **$scope** outside [angular world(see here)](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts), by using jquery's post.

You need to either wrap the assignments in a

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
  $scope.users = [];
  $scope.users = arg_result.Data;
});
```

or

Use angular's [$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) service that will do that for you. This is the preferred way.